# Ansible convert AnsibleUnsafeText string to dict

Tags: dictionary, ansible, ansible-2.x

In Ansible 2.9.27 I have an AnsibleUnsafeText variable named *my_var* and formed like this:

```
my_var: "var1:placeholder_var1,var2:placeholder_var2,var3:placeholder_var3,var4:,var5:foo_1,var6:foo_2,var7:[a,b,c],var8:foo3"
```

where:

- placeholder_varX is a placeholder for future use
- foo_X is a string value
- var7 is a list of items(a,b,c)
- may contain incorrect spaces or tabs before/after the commas or before/after the colons
- of course, in "my_var" the number of items "key:value" is variable
  and  there can be elements with only the key without value, eg var4

I want to convert it to a dictionary like this:

```
my_dict: {'var1': 'placeholder_var1', 'var2': 'placeholder_var2', 'var3': 'placeholder_var3', 'var4':, 'var5': 'foo_1', 'var6': 'foo_2', 'var7': ['a','b','c'], 'var8': 'foo3'}
```

with proper spaces after commas and after colons (for these not essential) and with quotes around keys and values ​and, for a list, around each element of the list (as per example above)

To do this i try:

1. Separate all the key:value elements paying attention to those keys that have as value a list identified by square brackets (example: var7:[a,b,c])
2. put proper spaces after commas (not after colons) and quotes around keys and values and for a list around each element of the list as well (as per example above)
3. recompose the dictionary

I made many attempts using 'regex_replace' and 'replace' for quoting string correctly but couldn't handle escaping correctly

Comment: But why do you want this?

Comment: Hi, the dict is required in a complex flow of activities. I can't change the input and i must have a dict for output.

Comment: `In Ansible 2.9.27` <= although there almost no chance this has an influence on the above issue, note that Ansible 2.9 has been deprecated and is not receiving any security releases for over 2 years now (see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/release_and_maintenance.html#ansible-core-support-matrix). You are very strongly encouraged to upgrade to a supported version (i.e. at least version 2.14)

Answer (score 1):

*Forenote: you are using a deprecated and unmaintained version of Ansible which you should upgrade ASAP although this is not the root cause of your issue. The below answer is using [fully qualified collection names (fqcn)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections_guide/collections_using_playbooks.html#using-collections-in-a-playbook) to reference modules as a current good practice. Please switch back to short names (e.g. `ansible.builtin.debug` => `debug`) if you did not yet upgrade as this will fail in your version*

---

Quick and dirty approach (although I don't know any cleaner method at this point given your description of the input...).

The only real blocker to parse your string as you receive it is the missing space after each colon. So just add the space, surround the string with curly braces and parse it as yaml.

```yaml
---
- name: Fix bad dict
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    my_var: "var1:placeholder_var1,var2:placeholder_var2,var3:placeholder_var3,var4:,var5:foo_1,var6:foo_2,var7:[a,b,c],var8:foo3"
    my_dict_you_want: {'var1': 'placeholder_var1', 'var2': 'placeholder_var2', 'var3': 'placeholder_var3', 'var4':, 'var5': 'foo_1', 'var6': 'foo_2', 'var7': ['a','b','c'], 'var8': 'foo3'} 
    my_dict_I_fixed: >-
      {{
        ('{' ~ (my_var | split(':') | join(': ')) ~ '}')
        | from_yaml
      }}


  tasks:
    - name: Show expected dict as reported in question
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: my_dict_you_want

    - name: Show dict as fixed by above jinja2 expression
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: my_dict_I_fixed

    - name: If any leftover doubt, make sure both are equal
      ansible.builtin.assert:
        that: my_dict_you_want == my_dict_I_fixed
```

Proof run:

```
PLAY [Fix bad dict] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show expected dict as reported in question] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_dict_you_want": {
        "var1": "placeholder_var1",
        "var2": "placeholder_var2",
        "var3": "placeholder_var3",
        "var4": null,
        "var5": "foo_1",
        "var6": "foo_2",
        "var7": [
            "a",
            "b",
            "c"
        ],
        "var8": "foo3"
    }
}

TASK [Show dict as fixed by above jinja2 expression] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_dict_I_fixed": {
        "var1": "placeholder_var1",
        "var2": "placeholder_var2",
        "var3": "placeholder_var3",
        "var4": null,
        "var5": "foo_1",
        "var6": "foo_2",
        "var7": [
            "a",
            "b",
            "c"
        ],
        "var8": "foo3"
    }
}

TASK [If any leftover doubt, make sure both are equal] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "All assertions passed"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```